# How to dereference and print memory from register in GDB?

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, gdb, reverse-engineering

I was reverse engineering a binary using GDB and analyzing register contents before a function call. The register `eax` contains the address of `"A string"` and the same address is stored in `ebp - 12`

```
(gdb) x/s $eax
0x56557100:     "A string"
(gdb) x/wx $ebp-12
0xffffd02c:     0x56557100
```

When I try to dereference the address I get a warning

```
(gdb) x/8c *($ebp -12)
Attempt to dereference a generic pointer.
```

But this pointer is secure to dereference

```
(gdb) x/s 0x56557100
0x56557100:     "A string"
```

**How to print the contents of a pointer in one line?**

Comment: Can you show us the output of `ptype $ebp`

Comment: `p/s *(char**)($ebp-12)`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick `ptype $ebp` outputs `type = void *`

Comment: @Jester `p/s *(char**)($ebp-12)` did the trick: `$1 = 0x56557100 "A string"`

Comment: Does a simpler `p (char*)($ebp-12)` work?  GDB might deref automatically for char*, I forget.

Comment: @PeterCordes no, it didn't. `$1 = 0xffffcfdc ""`. And `p (char**)($ebp-12)` also doesn't yields the expected result: `$2 = (char **) 0xffffcfdc`, but `p *$2` will then work

Comment: Oh I see, there's a pointer in memory at `($ebp-12)`, not literal string data.  Yes, you need a level of dereferencing to get GDB to take a pointer from memory and then dump the pointed-to memory.  So `p (char*)$eax` should print the string.

Comment: @Jester this should be an answer so that we all could +1 it.